# Left Join List<t> with Datatable -Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a `List<t>` and a `DataTable`. By using Linq I want to retrieve the list of products `List<Product>` that do not exists in the `DataTable`.

List of `product`(`List<Product>`)

```
Number    TechnicalDescription
1         This is the A item
2         This is the B item
3         This is the Z item
```

Table

```
Name         Description
A            This is the A item
B            This is the B item
C            This is the C item
D            This is the D item
```

Result: `List<Product>`

```
Number    TechnicalDescription
3         This is the Z item
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3845d/9)  is the fiddler SQL example of what I need, but using Linq.

I have tried this but does not work.

```
List<Product> productList = THE_LIST;
DataTable dtProducts = THE_TABLE;

var myNewList = from e in productList
                 join p in dtProducts.AsEnumerable()
                    on e.TechnicalDescription.ToLower()
                    equals p.Field<string>("Description").ToLower()
                    into productGroup
                 from p in productGroup.DefaultIfEmpty(new { ID = "0", TechnicalDescription = "" })
                 where p != null
                 select new
                 {
                     ID = e.ID,
                     TechnicalDescription = e.TechnicalDescription
                 };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var table = 
    dtProducts.AsEnumerable()
        .Select(r => p.Field<string>("Description")).ToList();
var result = 
    productList
       .Where(p => !table.Any(t => StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(t, p.TechnicalDescription)));
```

Comment: Great solution, only one suggestion `Equals(t, p.TechnicalDescription)`